# Commit message prefix in git

Tags: git, commit, commit-message

I have a requirement to prepend "ticket:N" to commit messages, where N is the number of the ticket I'm working on. But I keep forgetting about the prefix and remember about it only 5-6 commits later, so `--amend` won't help. Is it possible to set some warning, so git will warn me every time I forget to add the prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure every commit message follows some standard form, you can use [the `commit-msg` hook](http://schacon.github.io/git/githooks.html#_commit_msg).

But if you want to edit the commit message of some commit that is not the most recent, you can do that too using [`git rebase -i`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rebase.html#_interactive_mode), assuming you didn't push it yet.

Comment: Are the hooks working every time, no matter where I call them IDE or some GUI tool?

Comment: I think they should, but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter-branch` in combo with `--msg-filter` to update a range of commits.

For example, If you want to prepend `ticket:N` to every commit message from HEAD to xxxxxx:

`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'printf "ticket:N " && cat' xxxxxx..HEAD`

You can also append to the commit message by simply reversing `printf` and `cat`:

`git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat && printf "ticket:N"' xxxxxx..HEAD`

Comment: A slight problem with this approach is that it'll add a newline between the prefix and the rest of the message. You can avoid this by using 'printf "ticket:N " && cat' as the filter instead. (echo -n isn't very portable and is only available in some shells).

Comment: This answer saved me! My specific problem was adding JIRA ticket numbers. This answer is the basis for the solution https://tjdane.medium.com/add-a-jira-ticket-to-a-batch-of-old-commits-67557fb42d3e

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to add JIRA ticket numbers to your commits you can use this method https://tjdane.medium.com/add-a-jira-ticket-to-a-batch-of-old-commits-67557fb42d3e